# x-axis values not showing all in stacked bar chart

Tags: android, kotlin, bar-chart

Below you can find screen shot as well as my code;

[image]

Code is below;

```
      mChart = view.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);
        barWidth = 0.3f;
        barSpace = 0.02f;
        groupSpace = 0.4f;

        mChart.setDescription(null);
        mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

        ArrayList<BarEntry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
        yValues.add(new BarEntry(5, new float[]{10, 20, 30, 50}));
        yValues.add(new BarEntry(15, new float[]{12, 13}));
        yValues.add(new BarEntry(25, new float[]{15, 15}));
        yValues.add(new BarEntry(35, new float[]{17, 17}));

        BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(yValues, "");
        set.setColors(new int[]{Color.rgb(67, 67, 72), Color.rgb(124, 181, 236),
                Color.rgb(124, 181, 236), Color.rgb(124, 181, 236)});
        set.setStackLabels(new String[]{
                "Men", "Women", "fgdgfx", "gfdrhd"
        });
        BarData data = new BarData(set);
        data.setBarWidth(1.9f);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();

        final ArrayList xVals = new ArrayList();
        xVals.add("New");
        xVals.add("Accepted");
        xVals.add("Completed");
        xVals.add("Cancelled");

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0.4f);
        xAxis.setGranularity(4f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setSpaceTop(35f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        leftAxis.setGranularity(1.0f);
        leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_RIGHT);
        l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

Comment: which chart lib are you using ?

Comment: I am using MPAndroidChart

Comment: I want to show 4 values in x axis but it only shows single value

Comment: Okay Actually i got solution for another lib. that's why asked you.

Comment: It's a silly thing but can you try with `xVals.add("New");
xVals.add("Acc");
xVals.add("Com");
xVals.add("Can");`

Comment: That is not working

Comment: Please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `float value` with is got in the getFormattedValue method of the Formatter. The values which you are getting are(0,10,20,30) and the array you provided for the value of x-axis is only of size 4. That's why it was only printing the first x-value and not the rest.

Please change your code as followed.

```
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            try {
                return xVals.get((int) (value / 10));//dividing the value by 10 to get the multiplied value.
            } catch (Exception e){
                return "";
            }
        }
    });
```